# extract words of a certain language out of an xml file

Tags: xslt-3.0

given the following xml (which of course consists of many records),

i would like to output unique values out of it, and also generate a report, that would have the records each word was found.

```
    <collection>
<record>
  <controlfield tag="001">1</controlfield>
  <datafield tag="200" ind1="1" ind2=" ">
    <subfield code="a">Metafore po</subfield>
    <subfield code="e">Δοκίμια</subfield>
    <subfield code="f">Περικλής αρχαία Ελλάδα</subfield>
  </datafield>
  <datafield tag="210" ind1="|" ind2="|">
    <subfield code="a">Η Αθήνα</subfield>
    <subfield code="c">Νοέμβριος</subfield>
    <subfield code="d">1999</subfield>
  </datafield>
  <datafield tag="215" ind1=" " ind2=" ">
    <subfield code="a">263 s.</subfield>
  </datafield>
  <datafield tag="606" ind1="|" ind2=" ">
    <subfield code="3">250000087120140311174609</subfield>
    <subfield code="a">Πλάτων ιστορία</subfield>
  </datafield>
  <datafield tag="700" ind1=" " ind2="1">
    <subfield code="3">200000000120140228092156</subfield>
    <subfield code="4">070</subfield>
    <subfield code="a">Liper</subfield>
    <subfield code="b">Berit von der</subfield>
  </datafield>
</record>
<record>
  <controlfield tag="001">here text may also exist</controlfield>
  <datafield tag="200" ind1="1" ind2=" ">
    <subfield code="a">Metafore po</subfield>
    <subfield code="e">Δοκίμια</subfield>
    <subfield code="f">Περικλής</subfield>
  </datafield>
</collection>
```

desired output (xml format, or whatever is more easily achieved)

```
Δοκίμια: 1, here text may also exist
Περικλής: 1, here text may also exist
αρχαία: 1
Η: 1
```

etc...
regex i have tried with:
/[Α-Ωα-ω]{1,}/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you can treat that like a grouping problem:

```
  <xsl:template match="collection">
      <xsl:where-populated>
          <ul>
              <xsl:for-each-group select="record" group-by="datafield/subfield!tokenize(., '\s')[matches(., '\p{IsGreek}')]">
                  <li>
                      {current-grouping-key()} : <xsl:value-of select="current-group()/controlfield" separator=", "/>
                  </li>

              </xsl:for-each-group>
          </ul>
      </xsl:where-populated>
  </xsl:template>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWmuiKi/1 outputs

```
  <ul>
     <li>
        Δοκίμια : 1, here text may also exist
     </li>
     <li>
        Περικλής : 1, here text may also exist
     </li>
     <li>
        αρχαία : 1
     </li>
     <li>
        Ελλάδα : 1
     </li>
     <li>
        Η : 1
     </li>
     <li>
        Αθήνα : 1
     </li>
     <li>
        Νοέμβριος : 1
     </li>
     <li>
        Πλάτων : 1
     </li>
     <li>
        ιστορία : 1
     </li>
  </ul>
```

that way.

Of course identifying a "word" by simply tokenizing on white space is going to fail in mosts texts and languages, due to punctuation characters and language specific rules. But XSLT/XPath/XQuery regular expressions don't have a word break metacharacter anyway so somehow one has to use tokenize or analyze-string.

Comment: the above works perfect. Could one retrieve json output somehow, so as to store the results in mongodb? Also, seems i need to preprocess the xml, and remove ()[] characters for instance

Comment: XSLT 3 has a `json` output method https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-xquery-serialization-31/#json-output and with the XPath 3.1 data types `map` and `array` https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-31/#id-maps-and-arrays has support to construct JSON (like) data (https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#json) so creating JSON is possible and rather easy: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWmuiKi/2. For further problems think you need to ask a new question on that indicating the exact JSON structure you want, once you have digested the links and given it a try on your own.